# MIPS asembly, C - Why am I getting an undefined reference to main?

Tags: c, mips

I am trying to compile this simple C file on a debian machine using gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * my_name = "My Name";

extern unsigned int simple_op(unsigned int a, unsigned int b);

void main() {
    unsigned int a, b, result;

    printf("Simple op demo by %s at %s %s\n", my_name, __DATE__, __TIME__);

    printf("Please input a : ");
    scanf("%u", &a);

    printf("Please input b : ");
    scanf("%u", &b);

    result = simple_op(a, b);
    printf("simple_op(%u, %u) = %u(0x%08x)\n", a, b, result, result);
}
```

Using the following assembly file:

```
    .text
    .global simple_op
    .type   simple_op, @function
simple_op:
    add     $v0,$a0,$a1
    jr      $ra
```

But when I try to assemble the above file, I get this error:

```
In function `__start':
(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which is not allowing me to compile the C file. How do I fix this?

Comment: How do you assemble the file? Its trying to link.

Comment: Why is it not linking?

Comment: It _is_ trying to link, but it shouldn't as it needs the c-files code to link.